# Viable method of sharing our PHP project

Tags: php, web-development, web-applications, teamwork

We are two developers that have no previous experience in sharing one PHP project. In particular, cakePHP.

We both use NetBeans and we have set the project up as a "PHP application from a remote server". For the project we also use git + bitbucket for version control as well.

Now the problem is that whenever one of us makes any changes to the code and saves it, it gets updated on the server, but not in the other developer's environment.

Is this the right path we are taking for sharing the project?

How to make the code updates and how to avoid overriding other code?

Comment: see also: [What should be the workflow with a git repository?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89025/what-should-be-the-workflow-with-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read the Git book - http://git-scm.com/book

You need to commit your changes after you make them and push the data to bitbucket.

Once you have done this your partner can fetch the changes from Bitbucket and merge the changes, before repeating the process.

Version Control is designed to prevent you overriding each others code but you must first understand how to use it, there are also plenty of tutorials on youtube etc.

Comment: This is a fundamental purpose of git. Use it.